# Is there any synergy between the Death From Above strike and Dancing Blade Form stance?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

The stance lets you attack from 5 feet out. You must be adjacent to use the strike.

Can you use the strike from 5 feet out if you are in the stance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reach offered by *dancing blade form* isn’t any different from any other form of reach, which is to say, reach is a pretty common element to the game that the authors would have been aware of when using the word “adjacent” when writing *death from above*. So no, *death from above* uses the word “adjacent” when they could have said something about reach, so the official rule is “adjacent” only—and there is every indication that this was intentional.

On the other hand, allowing *death from above* to consider reach would not be imbalanced, if a DM wanted to do it.